# How do you add link and text on top of video background and make them responsive using html5?

Tags: html, html5-video

Trying to create a page for my project using a video as background but can't seem to put a link and text on top of video... I was able to do only one or the other. any help would be much appreciated! thank you in advance!

Comment: please share your minimum code, what have you tried?

Comment: Welcome! Could you post what you've tried so far? Code helps! There's a page on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which may help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample, the "testing" h1 is a link to google.com

https://codepen.io/carlos27/pen/rrpAWz

HTMTL

```
    <!--  Content  -->
<article>
  <h1><a href="http://www.google.ca" target="_blank">TESTING</a><br /><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span></h1>

</article>
<!--  Video is muted & autoplays, placed after major DOM elements for performance & has an image fallback  -->
<video autoplay loop id="video-background" muted>
  <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/158148793.hd.mp4?s=8e8741dbee251d5c35a759718d4b0976fbf38b6f&profile_id=119&oauth2_token_id=57447761" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
/*  Background fallback in case of IE8 & down, or in case video doens't load, such as with slower connections  */
  background: #333;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

a:link{
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* The only rule that matters */
#video-background {
/*  making the video fullscreen  */
  position: fixed;
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto; 
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
}

/* These just style the content */
article {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 10px;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 36px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Oswald, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 span {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

h1 span a {
  color: #fff;
}
```